# нахождение точки пересечения

Tags: python, python-3.x

у меня появился вопрос по поводу коллизии.
как сделать соприкосновение одной точки с двумя другими?[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

чего нужно добиться?
нужно, чтобы точки объекта1(красные точки) не могли пересечь коричневые точки объекта2( и не могли находиться в объекте2)
как же это можно реализовать на python 3.x с модулем pygame или с любым др. модулем

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Зная координаты двух "красных" точек и двух "коричневых" можно найти их току пересечения на плоскости.  Более того, ответить на вопрос, пересекаются-ли прямые, можно просто сравнив координаты этих  точек. Проверку можно легко написать самому. Вот тут люди развлекаются, например: https://habr.com/ru/post/267461/ и https://habr.com/ru/post/267037/